# How to set two decimal places in output

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal, currency

I'm trying to get Python to round up the output of a simple Tip Calculator program to two decimal places, but I've had no joy figuring it out so far. Below is the relevant section of code. I want the output to be printed in conventional dollars and cents format (e.g., $XX.XX)

```
bill = float(input("\n\nWhat is the bill for your meal?: $"))

low_tip = bill * .15
print("\nIf you would like to tip the waiter 15%, the amount of the \ntip is: $", low_tip)

low_total = bill + low_tip
print("\nSo, your total bill including a 15% tip would be: $", low_total)

high_tip = bill * .20
print("\nIf you would like to tip the waiter 20%, the amount of the \ntip is: $", high_tip)

high_total = bill + high_tip
print("\nSo, your total bill including a 20% tip would be: $", high_total)
```

Comment: See Answer to [python-format-decimal-with-a-minimum-number-of-decimal-places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181295/python-format-decimal-with-a-minimum-number-of-decimal-places) here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can format the float as a string before printing:

```
>>> '${0:.2f}'.format(15.5)
'$15.50'
```

Or using the `%` operator:

```
>>>'$%.2f' % 15.5
'$15.50'
```

The whole `print`s would then look like:

```
print("\nSo, your total bill including a 20% tip would be: ${0:.2f}".format(high_total))
```

Comment: Thanks! I just made all of the relevant replacements and this works like a charm. I also see how changing the ".2" to ".3" will give me three decimal places, etc.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim The full specification of the formatting fileds for the `format` method can be found [`here`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), in particular check the [`examples`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) while [`here`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) there is the documentation for `%`.

Comment: Thanks again. Those links have provided some very useful information.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed as "not a real question". It was asked in earnest, and answered promptly and succinctly by another user who understood my meaning completely and provided a very helpful solution.